# Why does a 'no resource error' appear while creating a button in android?

Tags: java, android

I tried creating my first app in android, wherein i tried putting a simple button. After following a step by step procedure of 'how to do it' from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html i found that there are unresolved errors in the activity_main.xml file in the following line: 
android:text="@string/scan" />

The error says error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/scan'). 
Can anyone tell me why and also explain how i can solve this?

I am pasting the whole xml file contents here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/scan" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here are the contents of sting.xml

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Myaxx</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</resources>
```

Here are the contents of the activity_main file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_scan" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says that you do not have a string with name scan in your strings.xml file.
do you have a string with name scan in your strings.xml?
If not try adding a string in strings.xml

simply do this

```
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Myaxx</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
    <string name="scan">scan</string>
</resources>
```

This means that you are having a string with name scan and value scan (In the last scenario) and you are referring it using @string/scan which returns the value of the string with name scan (@string/nameOfTheString)

Comment: when i expand the tree of the res folder i find that there are .png images there. Do i have to add anything there? Also please tell me where to find strings.xml. I am quite a beginner in android. So, the murkiness is quite understandable :)

Comment: well in the same resources folder you will have a values folder expand it and you will find the strings.xml file there

Comment: and also could you post that capture of the tree after expansion by editing the question.

Comment: but it expands as an ui instead of a simple file. This UI urges me to add, remove or navigate up/ down

Comment: quite understandably, i have to add a resource here, but how do i go about doing that?

Comment: okay i right clicked on the string.xml and then opened it with text editor. I am copy pasting the contents in my post

Comment: well now what you wanna display to the button?

Comment: the button should be called 'scan'

Comment: then do add this to the strings.xml file before the tag </resources> <string name="scan">scan</string>

Comment: check the edit and inform if it helped you.. Mostly just that's the thing we need to do. But if you have any more issues you can comment

Comment: cheers i am copy pasting the results of the activity_main.xml file